# How to get default Git branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

My team alternates between usage of dev and master as default branch for several repos and I would like to write a script that checks for the default branch when entering a directory.

When pull requests are opened in some of these repos, they either default to 'dev' or 'master' as the merge target.

I understand how to set this information but not retrieve it: 
https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/

Is there a git command available to determine default branch for remote repository?

Comment: The default branch is a github thing, not a git thing.

Comment: You can use the GitHub API, as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500461/how-do-i-find-the-default-branch-for-a-repository-using-the-github-v3-api

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Really? When creating a local bare repo and performing a clone on that there must still be some logic that determines which branch is checked out by default, right?

Comment: None of the below solution does work reliably for me: if I'm in branch `feature`, forked from `develop`, it will return me `develop` and not `master` (or `main`, from which `develop` is a fork)... Any help?

Comment: Question asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703168/how-to-get-the-default-for-the-master-branch-in-git

Comment: The question title is misleading now after Git 2.28 and `init.defaultBranch`. It should be changed to emphasize remotes and GitHub.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi How so? `git init` has a `--initial-branch` parameter which sets `HEAD`, and `git remote show` display the branch used for `HEAD`. Now that's a convention that mainly apply to bare repos, if your remote is an actual checkout the behavior will be quite different, but GH's behavior is consistent with any other bare repo remotes.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Tested with git 2.9.4 (but possibly works in other versions) in a repo cloned from Github:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | sed 's@^refs/remotes/origin/@@'
```

Sample output:

```
master
```

Or:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD --short
```

Sample output:

```
origin/master
```

Comment: if i change the default branch on the server side (github) this still gets the old default in an old but otherwise current clone (but fresh clones are fine).  How does one force an update here?

Comment: This works fine for origin, but when I tried getting the default branch for another remote, such as upstream in a forked github setup, I get "not a symbolic ref". I'm not git-savvy enough to understand why, but apparently ref/remotes/upstream won't exist at all. Radon8472's solution based on git remote worked for me though.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I run this I get: `fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref` with Git 2.19.1.

Comment: This method can fail or return incorrect results. The ref may be a hash that cannot be resolved to a branch rather than a symbolic reference. This can be solved by looking at HEAD as well. Still, in 6528 repositories I checked the two `git symbolic-ref` methods return wrong results (e.g. `master` rather than `develop` for `Alfresco/chef-alfresco`) in 172 cases. The `git remote show` method proposed by @Radon8472 is more reliable and seems to return the correct result in a few of the 172 diverging cases I verified by hand.

Comment: You can also use **basename** instead of sed `basename $(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD)`

Comment: @lfender6445 the command from this answer returns incorrect results for my repos. The other one with git remote show ... returns the correct branch.

Comment: To sync this symbolic ref from upstream, `git remote set-head origin --auto`. This updates both what is seen in `git remote show` and the symbolic ref referenced here.

Comment: I've just cloned [AlfrescoLabs/chef-alfresco](https://github.com/AlfrescoLabs/chef-alfresco), run this command, and correctly received `develop` as the master branch name.

Comment: This can fail if you don't have any remotes. If you're running it on the primary git repo, you have no remotes (you are the remote). In this case, just use "HEAD"

Comment: This was working nicely for me locally, but in a github action, produces: `fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref`.

Comment: may want to shorten the sed command: `git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | sed 's@.*/@@'`

Answer (score 172):

I found a way to detect the default-branch if it is not master.

```
git remote show [your_remote] | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p'
```

I tested it with multiple repo from gitlab, and it worked fine.
(for the most situations `[your_remote]` will be `origin`, run `git remote` to check the name of your remote)

Comment: This worked well for me, except that the cut command leaves a space before the actual branch name, which can cause problems when using this from scripts. I ended up using `git remote show upstream | grep "HEAD branch" | sed 's/.*: //'`

Comment: Best method so far. I don't even have refs/remotes/origin/HEAD for some reasons.

Comment: It depends how you names your remote, or if you have added a remote. Try to run `git remote` and see what it shows

Comment: @JHH 
You can also execute 'xargs' to get rid of spaces. That is: `git remote show [your_remote] | grep "HEAD branch" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | xargs`

Comment: I updated it to be like this to remove the space `git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD branch' | cut -d' ' -f5`

Comment: Be aware that this might not work for some (older) versions of git, provided you have ambiguous HEAD. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832269/git-remote-head-is-ambiguous)

Comment: It also doesn't work with localized (translated) Git. For example, in mine the output of `git remote show upstream` has `branch HEAD:`.

Comment: Does not work reliably for me: if I'm in branch `feature`, forked from `develop`, it will return me `develop` and not `master` (whose `develop` is a fork)... Any help?

Comment: Other options to strip out the space; 
* sed-based: `git remote show origin | sed  -e '/HEAD branch: /!d' -e '/HEAD branch: /s/.*: //'`
* perl-based: `git remote show origin | perl -ne 'if (/HEAD branch:\s*(.*)/) { print "$1"} '`

Comment: Using regex (js in my case), this pattern may be used: `result.match(/(?<=HEAD branch:).+/)?.[0].trim()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it says "Connection timed out". I guess that's because the command accesses the network instead of using the locally available info, I think it's worth mentioning in the post.

Comment: This works with Azure DevOps also.   I found awk simpler for the filtering, ie. `git remote show origin | awk -F': '  '/HEAD branch/ { print $2 }'`

Comment: This won't work if git is running under an non-English locale. For example with a German locale `HEAD branch` is spelled `Hauptbranch`. To fix this use: `LC_ALL=C git remote show origin | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p'`

Comment: @Slaven I AM running git under multiple german, and I never hat such issues, but thx for adding more informations to the command.

Which git version are you using that show this different translated name?

Comment: @Radon8472 CentOS 7 has git version 1.8.3.1 and the wording is "Hauptzweig". Debian 9 has 2.11.0 and the wording here is "Hauptbranch". Later Debians and Ubuntu also have "Hauptbranch". However Ubuntu 18.04 with git 2.17.1 has "HEAD branch". So maybe it does not seem to depend on the git version. (All of these tried with `LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8 git remote show origin`)

Comment: This is similar but seems to be much faster (a few ms vs a few seconds): `git branch -a | sed -n '/HEAD ->/s/.*\///p'`. You also don't need to know the name of the remote this way. Though it might not work if you have multiple remotes set up

Comment: For anyone looking for a **super fast** command, that looks in local references instead of going to the remote server, use this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384283/4561887. Put `time` in front and you'll see it runs in **0.003 sec** instead of the **0.621 sec** which the cmd above takes.

Comment: Similar but a bit cleaner way to get the default branch: ```git remote set-head origin -a && default_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD | sed 's|^origin/||') && echo "$default_branch"```. Do not use `symbolic-ref` as it will produce a wrong result if the head is not set. In contrast `rev-parse` would just fail in this case.

Comment: Also do not use `basename` as it'll give a wrong result if your default branch name has slash, e.g. `env/dev`

Comment: `cut` supports whitespace separation, so `git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD branch' | cut -wf4` has less cognitive overhead.

Answer (score 84):

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD` will print `origin/<default-branch-name>`. The [`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) answers are doing the same thing but need a longer argument.

If the `origin` repository changes its default branch name, then

`git remote set-head origin -a`

will retrieve the new default branch name.

Comment: This runs a lot faster than `git remote show`, because it uses local information without polling the remote. You can trim off the first 7 characters (i.e. "origin/") and get just the branch name with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD | cut -c8-`.

Comment: Isn't this actually the canonical answer, since it uses a plumbing command and doesn't require any utilities outside of git itself?

Comment: Answering myself - this is NOT the canonical answer since it only works in a repo created by cloning from the remote - not from a repo that you created and then added the remote by `git remote add` and pushed to it.

Comment: (still upvoting since it's the best answer in the likely use case of a script where you know that you've cloned the repo from a remote)

Comment: Doesn't work for me: when executed as in the answer, the only stdout I get is `origin/HEAD`, and there are also errors `warning: ignoring dangling symref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`. If I append to the command a `-- .`, it says `warning: ignoring dangling symref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, `fatal: bad revision 'origin/HEAD'`. However, the `git symbolic-ref` answer this answer refers to works for me.

Comment: Hello, I recently created an alias based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950967/10095231

Comment: `basename \`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD\``

Comment: This answer helped me learn the role of `origin/HEAD`; specifying `origin/HEAD` explicitly worked perfectly for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

There doesn't seem to be an answer that doesn't require cloning so far

This requires git 2.8.0 or newer

```
$ git ls-remote --symref git@github.com:pre-commit/pre-commit.github.io HEAD
ref: refs/heads/real_master HEAD
e100a6a3c72b4e54f0d176f791dfd2dbd7eb5fa7    HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. I added awk to take the branch name:

`git ls-remote --symref https://github.com/hnakamur/ltsvlog HEAD | awk '/^ref:/ {sub(/refs\/heads\//, "", $2); print $2}'`

Comment: Thats a nice answer,  but it does only give you the current HEAD of the remote, and it gives no information which one is the default-branch.

Comment: `real_master` here is the default branch

Comment: @Radon8472 On GitHub, isn't the HEAD on a remote repo the default branch?

Comment: It would be handy if there were an option to show _only_ the 'symref'. Also, note that the URL can be replaced by a named remote such as `origin` or `.`.

Comment: @MartinBraun no its not. Many bare remotes don`t have a head. And when you e.g. use a remote for deploy, the head can be whatever the user wanted.

So Head has nothing to do with default branch, HEAD tells you what point of history you currently have checked out. You can even have a detached head, what is not even linked to any branch.

Answer (score 30):

This question is a bit old but in case anyone comes across this more recently...

```sh
git remote show <remote_name> | awk '/HEAD branch/ {print $NF}'
```

That will also only display the branch name, not including any of the whitespace or other nonsense.

I like to save this using a couple git aliases (I have a bunch of useful aliases like this):

```sh
upstream-name = !git remote | egrep -o '(upstream|origin)' | tail -1
head-branch = !git remote show $(git upstream-name) | awk '/HEAD branch/ {print $NF}'
```

I use "upstream" and "origin" as my remotes almost 100% of the time ("upstream" when I go with a [Fork & Pull](https://reflectoring.io/github-fork-and-pull/) workflow... which is often). Your use case may not need the `upstream-name` alias, I just find it useful.

Comment: A possible PowerShell solution: `(git remote show origin | Select-String "HEAD branch: " -Raw).Split(' ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]`

Comment: git remote show is slow because it queries the server. Using the -n option it's faster but only gives back the list of branches already known. That might not be the best solution but one could write the following: `git remote show origin -n | grep -c main &> /dev/null && echo main || echo master`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it says "Connection timed out". I guess that's because the command accesses the network instead of using the locally available info, I think it's worth mentioning in the post.

Comment: This will fail if git is localized. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch#comment126528129_50056710

Comment: This works great with git 2.37.1!

Comment: Its similar to my solution, and I like the "upstream-name" command, but unforunelly it will not work if your upstream is named differently than "upstream" or "origin"

Comment: This could have been added as a comment to Radon8472's answer, using awk is nicer but it's essentially doing the same thing. There are better answers too.

Answer (score 22):

There is a *--short* option to *git symbolic-ref*. So my preferred command:

```
$ basename $(git symbolic-ref --short refs/remotes/origin/HEAD) 
master
```

Comment: For remote it would still be `git symbolic-ref --short refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | sed 's@^origin/@@'`

Comment: It's a path, so in most POSIX-y shells you can also just use basename to get the last component. :D  `basename $(git symbolic-ref --short refs/remotes/origin/HEAD)`

Comment: basename does not work for all branch names as they can contain slashes

Comment: it does not work
```$ git symbolic-ref --short refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref

;$ git --version
git version 2.36.1
```

Comment: I like this command because compared to many of the others it is **super fast**! I left a comment about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch/49384283#comment130262457_50056710

Comment: Gives only `fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref` for me

Comment: This fails in GitHub actions despite working locally for me.

Answer (score 17):

### Requirements

You need `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and it is only set when cloning. Otherwise you need to set it yourself with

`git remote set-head origin -a`

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639383/how-to-add-missing-origin-head-in-git-repo)

### Command

The following command will list the HEAD branch, no matter how you have named your remotes:

```bash
git branch --remotes --list '*/HEAD'
```

From that you can extract the default branch like this:

```bash
git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

(using short variants of the `git branch` arguments).

If your shell does not have the `rev` command, you can use `awk` instead:

```
git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: I am working somewhere that `stage` is used as trunk for development, and `master` is used for deployment. This gives me `stage`, which is what I wanted – thanks!

Comment: Gives for me `bash: rev: command not found` and `fatal: -a and -r options to 'git branch' do not make sense with a branch name
`

Comment: @Radon8472 If your shell does not have the `rev` command, you can use `awk` instead: `git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @Henry this gives `fatal: -a and -r options to 'git branch' do not make sense with a branch name
`

Comment: @Radon8472 Where does the `-a` option come from? What do you get when you run just the first command: `git branch -rl '*/HEAD'` ?

Answer (score 16):

This is possible to get with the gh cli tool (tested v2.0.0)

```bash
gh repo view --json defaultBranchRef --jq .defaultBranchRef.name
```

Answer (score 15):

As noted by other answerers, the concept of a default branch is a GitHub thing doesn't really make sense (in the lofty sense) of Git (there's a reasonably good (if under-appreciated) comment here gets into it a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710958/2521092) but in practice, we all know what that means.

Since the original asking of this question, Git 2.28 added `init.defaultBranch`, allowing a different initial branch than `master`, and a lot of projects are now using `main`.  That's good.  Most of the answers here rely on checking a remote, but that relies on there actually *being* a remote, and that there exists a reliable and consistent naming scheme to those remotes.  Those are probably (increasingly?) reasonable assumptions, but it's not a guarantee, and I don't find that any of the major answers here fail nicely.

Moreover, my main use case is using the name of the default branch for various git aliases (e.g. `lm = log main..HEAD`).  I'd like to use the same aliases without thinking about it too much, regardless of an external repo using `master` or a local using `main` with no remote.  Git and its config can't really "store" information, so there's no way to set ahead of time what the current repository's main branch is.  As such, any alias that wants to, say, show commits between the main branch and HEAD can't assume `git log master..HEAD` or `git log main..HEAD` will work.

Thus, I define a `default-branch` alias in Git that figures out the default branch and then supply that to other aliases.  This is a pain since a simple `lm = log main..HEAD` has to instead become `lm = "!git log $(git default-branch)..HEAD"` but here we are:

`default-branch = "!git branch --sort=-refname | grep -o -m1 '\\b\\(main\\|master\\|dev\\)\\b'"`

This simply gets the branch names then finds the first one in a defined list.  If there's a `main`, use that; if not and there's a `master`, use that.  I also have `dev` in there as a tertiary option some folks use.

This is sort of similar to what @henrik-n does in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622363/2521092, but I do it in Git itself rather than the shell, and I think it has some more optionality.

Comment: But your way does not realy check what is assignes as default-branch in remote. What if the defaultbrauch is called e.g. `my-default` or anytrhing other?

Comment: In my second paragraph, I detail one of the main reasons I find this useful: repositories *without* a remote.

Comment: Yes, I was reading this, but the question above asked how to get it from remote repo. So you answer is informativ, but it is no answer to the question that was asked here

Comment: The whole "main" change was made by people who had no idea how much it would break.

Comment: “That's good. Most of the answers here rely on checking a remote, but that relies on there actually being a remote,[…]”—That’s what OP asked for. “Is there a git command available to determine default branch for remote repository?”

Comment: `init.defaultBranch` only configures which branch is created for new repos. It doesn't really have anything to do with the "default" branch for an existing repo.

Answer (score 8):

All other answers made too many assumptions, this is the only way that worked for me. This works regardless of what branch you're currently on, doesn't assume the `origin/HEAD` ref exists locally, and will always reflect the current default branch even if it's been changed.

The only drawback is that it alters the local `origin/HEAD` ref, but that shouldn't generally be a problem.

Allow git to set your `origin/HEAD`, determining what branch to use automatically:

```
$ git remote set-head origin --auto
origin/HEAD set to main
```

Then, get a string containing the name of the default branch:

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
origin/main
```

Alternatively, for a one-line solution:

```
$ git remote set-head origin --auto >/dev/null 2>&1 && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
origin/main
```

Comment: What are the potential drawbacks of altering the local `origin/HEAD` ref?

Comment: @ChrisLong Basically none, but it could confuse scripts or someone could have a specific reason to want to keep their origin/HEAD at some outdated value.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted a shell script to know whether the branch is "master" or "main".

For that purpose, this seems good enough:

```
[ -f "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/refs/heads/master" ] && echo master || echo main
```

If you know it will always be called from the root directory of the repo, it can be simplified to

```
[ -f .git/refs/heads/master ] && echo master || echo main
```

I'm using this in my Git aliases like so: https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/commit/6815bd95770afab2936fb6202b1ee5e82cb9662b

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a git command available to determine default branch for remote repository?

This list the default *local* repository branch:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
```

The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference) can [show the default branch with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084284/6309) using its [CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/):

```
gh api /repos/{owner}/{repo} --jq '.default_branch'
```

Answer (score 5):

If like this question you are trying to get a *GitHub* default branch--not some other git server:

You can get the default branch using the [`/repos` GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos). It's the `default_branch` field of the response:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/darthwalsh/bootstrappingCIL | \
      jq --raw-output .default_branch
master
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me with Git 2.1.10, using a repository cloned from GitHub:

```
git branch -r --points-at refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

A major problem with this approach is that it lists *every* remote branch pointing to HEAD; however, the output includes a hint:

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/test123
```

So you can post-process the output with `grep` or similar to find the one with the arrow:

```
git branch -r --points-at refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | grep '\->' | cut -d' ' -f5 | cut -d/ -f2
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` will not exist only if you've cloned the repo not if you've created/authored it. `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/master` can be used to link refs ( but that defeats the point of this question :) )

Answer (score 4):

From git 2.28.0 and above:

```
$ git config --get init.defaultBranch || echo master
```

Comment: This works well for me `git config --get init.defaultBranch`

Comment: It only shows what will be default branch when create git repo. Use this instead to get default branch for current repo https://stackoverflow.com/a/67170894/588759

Comment: `git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH` is simpler.

Comment: @Guildenstern this gives the first branch created by `git init`, not what is the "default" branch on a remote.

Comment: @bric3 The answer I replied to is about `init.defaultBranch`, not whatever GitHub does. I don’t know why you are replying to me.

Comment: @Guildenstern The OP question is about default branch for github repos and `git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH` may not give the correct answer, in the same way as @rofrol replied about `git config --get init.defaultBranch`.

Comment: @bric3 I was replying to the answerer, not to the question/OP!

Answer (score 1):

I'll add yet another answer, based on the other answers. I didn't like any of the other answers because querying a remote is slow, but I also didn't want a "local-only" solution.

I use this (long) alias:

```
head-branch = "!f() { gitHeadsDir=\"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/refs/heads\"; if [ -f \"$gitHeadsDir/main\" ]; then echo 'main'; elif [ -f \"$gitHeadsDir/master\" ]; then echo 'master'; else git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD branch' | cut -d' ' -f5; fi; }; f"
```

The above basically does this:

- if a local branch named `main` exists, use that
- if a local branch named `master` exists, use that
- otherwise, fall back to checking the remote (which is much slower)

This works for 99 % of use cases (and all of my use cases), including:

- a "regular" cloned repository
- a brand new repository, which might not even have a remote (yet).

You can still easily "break" this by creating a local branch named `main` or `master` (or both), even if that's not actually the default branch. This will also fail if you don't have a remote, and your default branch name is neither `main` or `master`. But in those cases you're most likely *trying* to break it. ;-)

I'm checking for `main` first, since if you have both `main` *and* `master`, you're likely in the process of switching from `master` to `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some context about remote names to the excellent answers of danielkza or Jerrey Yasskin.

So the example show it's possible to get the default branch of the remote named `origin`.

```bash
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
origin/master
```

But if the remote are not named `origin` this could fail

```bash
$ git remote show
bric3
upstream

$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD
origin/HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Also not all remote have a default branch

```bash
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref bric3/HEAD
bric3/HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'bric3/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ ls .git/refs/remotes/bric3/HEAD
".git/refs/remotes/bric3/HEAD": No such file or directory (os error 2)

$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref upstream/HEAD
upstream/master

$ ls .git/refs/remotes/upstream/HEAD
.git/refs/remotes/upstream/HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bit of a workaround solution but this seems to work:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score -3):

```bash
> git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH
master
```

From [the docs for `git var`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#Documentation/git-var.txt-GITDEFAULTBRANCH):

> `GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH`: The name of the first branch created in newly initialized repositories.

[This variable was added in git 2.35.](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e06c9e1df28e04bbf013840c6c50ce1be41b9583)

Comment: This shows _your local_ config, affecting new repos you'll `git init` in future.  It shows me same value even if I chdir into directories where the remote defaults to `main` vs `master` vs `gh-pages`.