# How to get a git repository's default branch in Ruby's "rugged" gem?

Tags: ruby, git, rugged

Related to [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch)

I'm trying to port a Bash script to Ruby. The script uses `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` to get a repo's default branch.

Is there a way to combine [rugged's `repo.branches.each_name(:local)`](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#branches) with some other command to find the default branch?

Or am I thinking too complicated and there is a useful default in rugged that I am missing? The script needs to continue by creating a new branch off the default/latest one, check-it out, commit something standardized, push the new branch, and open a pull request against that base branch.

Comment: How exactly does `git branch --list | head -1 | sed -E 's/ *//'` get the *default* branch? It only returns the first branch from the list of branches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch

Comment: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: I guessed that the list had the HEAD branch on top. In my use so far, this worked, also when the default branch on GitHub was called `dev` or `src`.

Comment: I explicitly that Q already, see the Linked section to the top right of this ;-) I'll add that suggestion to the Bash script, but the point of this question is how to port that behaviour to Ruby.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand what *deafult* branch means to you - is it a) currently checked-out branch b) branch is automatically checked-out after cloning the repository?

Comment: The one that is specified in GitHub under `/settings/branches`, because repo owners often request PRs to be submitted against that one. If `git clone --depth=…` clones that one by default, the problem is already solved.