# How do you find the default branch of a remote git repository?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

Different repositories name their primary development branches differently (e.g. `main`, `gh-pages`, `master`, etc.), and scripts meant to work with multiple repositories need an automated way to discover the current repository's default branch name.

What `git` command returns that name?

Comment: **See Also**: [How to get default branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28666357/1366033)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD` will print `origin/<default-branch-name>`.

If the `origin` repository changes its default branch name, then `git remote set-head origin -a` will retrieve the new default branch name.

Comment: origin/HEAD may not always be available! If you create the repo and did not clone it, there's a good chance it won't be there!