# How do you print the default remote name from the git command line?

Tags: git

My local repository has two remotes:

```bash
$ git remote show
origin
upstream
```

How do I know which one will be pushed to if I run `git push`?

(Note: I'm asking this question so I can answer it.)

---

See also:

- [How do you find the default branch of a remote git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62352646/how-do-you-find-the-default-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

  > `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD` will print `origin/<default-branch-name>`.
- [How to get default Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/how-to-get-default-git-branch)

The difference? I'm asking for the default *remote* (e.g., `<repository>` in `git push [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]`), not the remote's default *branch*.

Answer (score 2):

### Command

```bash
git config "branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).remote" || echo "origin"
```

### Details

[The `git push` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_description) says:

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the `<repository>` argument, `branch.*.remote` configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to `origin`.

It took me a bit to realize what that `*` in `branch.*.remote` meant. It's the name of your current branch. [As this comment says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-do-i-get-the-current-branch-name-in-git#comment22090264_12142066), you can get it from `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.

Putting that all together, you can get the `<repository>` argument of running `git push` with this command:

```bash
git config "branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).remote" || echo "origin"
```

### Known limitations

This will print `origin` if `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` errors for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Branches in git can be set to "track" upstream branches, in other words when you `git push` it is dependent on which branch you are currently on, as to which location it will push to.

You can see all the upstreams branches by doing:

```
git branch -vv
```

However that can be very verbose, if you have a lot of branches and I don't think there is a way to filter that (other than by piping it to grep).

Instead you can print the config for a specific local branch with:

```
git config --get branch.MY_LOCAL_BRANCH.remote
git config --get branch.MY_LOCAL_BRANCH.merge

For example:
git config --get branch.main.remote
git config --get branch.main.merge
```

All these commands are really doing is reading the config file under your `.git` folder so you could just do:

`cat .git/config`

Comment: `git branch -r` can provide useful information too