# GitHub actions: default branch variable

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Is there any smart way to determine the default branch in GitHub actions?

Now I need to write something like:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

is there a way to write something like the code below?

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - $default-branch
```

I tried to google but found nothing

Answer (score 56):

I accidentally found a really nice way to solve this. That evalutes to the branch name, e.g. master.

```
${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}
```

Also, found out the hard way that that `always()` is side-effecting: my job was getting skipped if `always()` was not called even though the other clause was true.

This works to run a job only when running on default branch

```
  if: ${{ always() && format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch) == github.ref }}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for an additional step or other crazy workarounds.

Comment: Updating to this method in https://github.com/manubot/rootstock/pull/452. I just hope the github.event context contains this field for all potential event types.

Comment: The `${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}` expression can be used inside jobs, but not to define an event trigger under the `on:` statement as this question requests

Comment: This seems not to work with schedule triggers.

Comment: FYI GitHub [fixed](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/12269#discussioncomment-3747667) the scheduled workflow context on 2022-07-27. You can see that `scheduled` jobs now contain the full `github.event.repository` context in [this dump actions context job](https://github.com/dhimmel/dump-actions-context/actions/runs/3283984929/jobs/5409384642#step:2:41).

Comment: This approach worked for me without the `always()`. Just `if: github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch)`.

Comment: This statement worked for me in the if statement:

`if: github.ref == github.event.repository.default_branch`

Comment: you can avoid the format string by using this instead `github.event.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch`

Comment: I think that should be `github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch`

Answer (score 33):

`$default-branch` can be used in Workflow templates, but not in Workflows. The branch will become hard-coded in the Workflow upon initialization, and will have to be manually maintained. [[1]](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/pull/590#issuecomment-672360634)

Blog post: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-22-github-actions-better-support-for-alternative-default-branch-names/

Comment: Damn! They could have done it right and add a placeholder for default branch.

Answer (score 13):

```
- if: github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch)
  run: echo "On the default branch"
- if: github.ref != format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch)
  run: echo "Not on the default branch"
```

**Edit 2023**

As Elijah pointed out in the comments, a new `ref_name` field is now available. Simplified:

```
- if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch
  run: echo "On the default branch"
- if: github.ref_name != github.event.repository.default_branch
  run: echo "Not on the default branch"
```

Comment: Oddly, I looked at the example docs to print out the context and it looks like this is found in github.event.repository.master_branch

Comment: @ChrisKnoll - Do you have a link to the build? That does sound odd indeed.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I'm having trouble finding the reference in the doucmentation, however, to inspect what was in the payload object, I 'echoed' the contents of the github.event JSON and found the element in the object graph.

Comment: Use `github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch` to avoid the format string.

Answer (score 5):

You can run jobs conditionally on the default branch:

```
jobs:
  job-one:
    if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch
    ...
```

You can run steps conditionally on the default branch:

```
jobs:
  job-one:
    steps:
      - name: step one
        if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved reaching GitHub context and particularly

```
github.event.repository.default_branch
```

Comment: Please delete your answer. `github.event.repository.default_branch` is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$default-branch` in a template, and then when that template is rendered into a new repo, it will be replaced with the (then) default branch name for the repo, but that is a very limited use case and still does not help you when the name of the default branch changes. The best I have come up with is to list the all the default branch names in the organization, like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
      - root
      - default
      - production
```

and then you can either trust that the repos will not have non-default branches with those names, or start the jobs and then filter them by adding an `if` condition like

```
if: github.event.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', github.event.repository.default_branch)
```

#### Side note

For most events

```
${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}
```

is available and works fine, but not when running `schedule` events via `cron`. When `github.event_name == "schedule"` the only element in `github.event` is `schedule` (the `cron` string that triggered the run).

When running inside a GitHub action on at GitHub runner with `gh` available, this more reliably gets you the default branch name:

```
gh repo view --json defaultBranchRef --jq .defaultBranchRef.name
```

However, this does not help the OP when you want to make the default branch the target that triggers the run.

Comment: `github.event.push.ref` is "". I used `if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch` instead

Comment: @Elijah `github.event.push.ref` only works on `push` events, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: My GH Actions was also push driven: https://github.com/elibroftw/blog.elijahlopez.ca/blob/master/.github/workflows/gh-pages.yml#L3. Not to mention even the GH Actions vscode extension adds a linting error for github.event.push.ref. here is proof that the event.push.ref is faulty https://github.com/elibroftw/blog.elijahlopez.ca/actions/runs/6916089771/job/18815753810. Also, because you are defensive, your format string is also incorrect https://github.com/elibroftw/blog.elijahlopez.ca/actions/runs/6915840457/job/18815230745.

Comment: @Elijah Thank you for the corrections. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this step to your job:

```yaml
    - name: Determine default branch
      run: |
        DEFAULT_BRANCH=$(git remote show origin | awk '/HEAD branch/ {print $NF}')
        echo "default_branch=$DEFAULT_BRANCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "default_branch_ref=refs/heads/$DEFAULT_BRANCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

That will add a `default_branch` and a `default_branch_ref` variable to the `env` enivronment variables.
You can then access the default branch name with `${{ env.default_branch }}` in subsequent steps.
The `default_branch_ref` variable is useful for directly comparing against `github.ref` to determine whether you are on the default branch.

This method uses the current method of setting environment variables to use in later steps [[1]](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and JoeLinux's method for determining the default branch name [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357104/1960959).

Full example workflow:

```yaml
name: ci

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Determine default branch
      run: |
        DEFAULT_BRANCH=$(git remote show origin | awk '/HEAD branch/ {print $NF}')
        echo "default_branch=$DEFAULT_BRANCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "default_branch_ref=refs/heads/$DEFAULT_BRANCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: debug
      run: echo ${{ env.default_branch }}

    - name: Deploy
      if: github.ref == env.default_branch_ref
      run: echo "Run!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this does not work in the specific code of the question, it does cover the title and main question written.

The easier thing you can do, is just specify an environment variable:

```yaml
env:
  DEFAULT_BRANCH: refs/heads/${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, there will be a better way to do this in the future. Until then, you can use the GitHub API and save the result in a named step output.

e.g.

```
    - name: Extract default branch name
      shell: bash
      run: |
        owner="my-org"
        repo="repo_x"
        branch=$(curl -L -H 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
            https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo} \
            | jq .default_branch)
        echo "##[set-output name=default_branch;]$(echo ${branch})"
      id: repo_x
...
${{ steps.repo_x.outputs.default_branch }}
```