# How to run GitHub Actions workflows on pull request to default branch regardless of the name of the default branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub Actions support running [workflows for pull requests targets specific branches](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore) but the names of the branches must be specified, thus if we want it to run on repositories with default branch named `main`:

```
  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - main
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to share the same workflow across multiple repositories **without the need to asking each repositories to specify their default branch name, and the workflow can work upon renaming default branches**. Is there a way to just run the workflow upon pull requests to default branch without specifying all the possible default branch names across these repositories as below?

I want to avoid:

```
  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - main
      - master
      - develop
      - dev
      - i-dont-know-what-else
      - ${{ remember-to-update-this-after-renaming-default-branch }}
```

I've tried listing all possible default branch names and use a variable but these are not elegant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub actions: default branch variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781462/github-actions-default-branch-variable)

Comment: @GuiFalourd, that's an interesting find, but somehow it's not documented on https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types, yet it can be found on https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos. Anyway I went ahead to try with `- ${{ github.event.repository.default_branch }}` but only ending up with an error: `Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.event.repository.default_branch`.

Comment: I don't think this solution works at the workflow level 

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the conditional `github.ref == github.event.repository.default_branch`.

Here's an example which only runs when a PR is merged into the default branch.

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  example:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged && github.ref == github.event.repository.default_branch
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```