# A git alias to accept both main and master branch names?

Tags: git, git-config

I work on several projects with some having `main` and some `master` as default branch. I can't rename all the projects with one or other name because not all are managed by me. I know the `.gitconfig` alias system is very wide so I'm wondering if there is a way to accept both names for every command where there are involved. So far I only found [this](https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2020/06/on-git-master-main-and-inclusion.html) but it involves modify each individual command and using `!sh -c` which is not very 'pretty'. The ideal would be to also testing if both branches actually exist in the repo to avoid mistakes.
I tried adding `master = main` at the beginning of .gitconfig `[alias]` section but it don't works in either way.

Comment: If these are your own checkouts, you can use whatever branch names you like. You can have a local branch named `master` that tracks a remote branch named `main`. When you clone a repository, the initial branch may be named `main`, but you can rename it to `master` (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good thing to solve local problems. However I would want this to also work for origin/main and origin/master.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the *default* branch of a *remote* repository, regardless of name, you can look at `.git/refs/remote/<remote name>/HEAD`.

For instance:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
$ awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
master
```

Then you can switch to the local branch of the same name:

```
git switch $(awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD)
```

Comment: In my repo there is no `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` I'm on git 2.31.1

Comment: @cowlicks: The remote might be named differently, for example `upstream`. Just as `master`/`main`, the default remote names are only a convention.

Comment: @cowlicks That may also happen if a remote is added after `git init` (or after cloning the repository). I have one such repository that has multiple remotes, but only `origin` has a `HEAD` file in `.git/refs/remotes`. If that's the case, running `git remote set-head origin --auto` should fix it; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895556/10095231

Comment: `sed 's|.*/||' .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is an alternative to the awk statement

Comment: A version based on git command instead of git files (which will work also in subdirectories): `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD` (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397081/ )

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to do it in an alias in your .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    com="!f() { git checkout master 2>/dev/null || git checkout main; }; f"
```

`com` stands for "`c`heck`o`ut `m`aster/`m`ain". Just easier to type `git com`.
Note: only works if the main branch names in the repos you work on are either `master` or `main`.
Why anyone would make different main branch names I have no idea since there really isn't any programmatic advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a practical way to do that.  You could approximate that by renaming the branch locally; this doesn't affect the remote or any other user, so it doesn't matter whether it's "your" project to manage.

```
git checkout master
git branch -m main
```

But I don't really recommend it.  The downside to this (or to your original "alias" idea if you could get it to work) is that you will likely reinforce your lack of knowledge about which repos use which name.  For those cases when you need the remote tracking ref name (`origin/master` or `origin/main`), and for those cases where you're communicating with other users of the repo, this is likely to increase confusion.

Comment: Yes I see. I didn't think about communication problems

Comment: "You could approximate that by renaming the branch locally; this doesn't affect the remote or any other user" It could if you ever merge locally (or pull from other branches, as is done on the Linux kernel workflow) and push the result, as the branch name is part of the auto-generated merge commit message. Besides the cited communication problems (of when mentioning the branches I assume), I'd find it rather confusing (and inconsistent) if the history were to sometimes contain merges of non-existent remote branches.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust version of IMSoP's answer is

```sh
awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' \
  $(find ./.git/refs/remotes/ -type f -name 'HEAD' | head -1)
```

It `find`s the `HEAD` first, and thus the branch name, regardless of the name of the remote(s, or their number).

---

Edit: My below, initial answer is more brittle than the above.

> testing if both branches actually exist in the repo to avoid mistakes.

Specifically for switching to the default branch, I use this bash function during this… transition period.

```
gsm () {  # Switch to main or master branch
  git branch --list | grep ' master$'
  if   [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then git switch master
  elif [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then git branch --list | grep ' main$'
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then git switch main; fi
  else  # neither exists
    git switch -c main
  fi
}
```

I haven't tested this for each combination of `master` and/or `main` being present and/or absent, though.

Comment: I guess `git switch` is an alias for checkout ?

Comment: @Nonoreve "git checkout" did rather too many different things, so "git switch" is [the new command for switching branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), while "git restore" is taking over things like "undo local changes to this file"

Comment: thanks I didn't knew this new feature. Also I think you answering made this question active again witch made someone give an answer even closer to what I thought of.

Comment: "`find ./.git/refs/remotes/* -type f -name 'HEAD'`" Note that if there are multiple remotes with a HEAD reference, this will print multiple values. Speaking of robustness, since `find` is already being used, I suppose that `*` can be dropped, as if it expands to funny characters I think that they could cause issues; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004. Suggestion: `find ./.git/refs/remotes/ -type f -name 'HEAD' -exec awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' '{}' +`

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397081/10095231:

> `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD` will print
> `origin/<default-branch-name>`.

To strip the remote part (i.e.: "origin") from it and only print what is to the
right of (the last) `/`:

```sh
basename "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref origin/HEAD)"
```

To support multiple remotes, something like the following could be done (inside
a script or a function, for example):

```sh
test -n "$1" && r="$1" || r=origin
basename "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref "$r"/HEAD)"
```

Now inside a git alias, called "defbranch":

```
[alias]
    defbranch = "!f() { test -n \"$1\" && r=\"$1\" || r=origin; \
      basename \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref \"$r\"/HEAD)\"; }; f"
```

It should be portable enough to work on any POSIX-compatible shell.

Add the above code to your git config file (e.g.: `~/.gitconfig`) and use it
like so:

```
$ git defbranch
master
```

To print the default branch of **another remote**, just specify its name as the
first argument:

```
$ git defbranch origin2
main
```

Examples of using the alias with other git commands:

```sh
git checkout "$(git defbranch)"
git merge "$(git defbranch)"
```

For increased ergonomics, you could also store the default branch name in a
variable and then use just the variable:

```sh
db="$(git defbranch)"
git checkout "$db"
git merge "$db"
```