# Command to automatically checkout the default branch

Tags: git

More projects are changing their default branch from `master` to something else like `main`. Is there a way to checkout the `default` branch without having to look up if it's called `master` or `main` or something completely different?

Comment: You may create your own alias for this, using other aliases like those provided by the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357104/1887976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch/61357104#comment118981819_61357104

Comment: [mjd2021usa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16619948) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704176) saying "While it's not exactly what you asked for, it achieves the same goal. Checkout: [https://joshtronic.com/2020/08/09/how-to-get-the-default-git-branch/](https://joshtronic.com/2020/08/09/how-to-get-the-default-git-branch/)"

Answer (score 0):

```bash
function gcm() {
    git remote show "${1:-origin}" | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p' | xargs git checkout
}
```

Put this into your bashrc or zshrc. Use as `gcm` if your upstream is named origin (default value). Otherwise, use `gcm <name>` to get and then checkout the default branch in upstream repository. gcm stands for Git Checkout M[ain or aster].