# git alias that treats `main` and `master` the same

Tags: git, alias

I have (amongst others) git aliases:

- `grm`: `git rebase master`
- `grim`: `git rebase -i master`

The development community as a whole is moving away from the use for `master` for the default branch, in favour of `main`. *(For reasons relating to historical associations)*

Unfortunately the community isn't doing that uniformly, and I frequently switch between projects, so I'd have to keep editing my aliases.

Is there any way to write the alias so that it interacts with "whichever of `master` or `main` exists in this repo"? (Happy to have it assume that only one of the 2 exists, locally)

---

Re: Suggested answer.
The problem is not "I as a human don't know which is in use in this repo"; That's trivial to identify by glancing at the history. It's that my *alias* doesn't know.

I'd assumed that the solution would be something that "tries both options" in some way, but a solution that uses the linked question to determine the correct answer directly *and then uses that answer* would also work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, uhhh ... I suppose that could be the first step, yes ... I don't know enough bash to know how/whether I can use that to then run `git rebase <that_branch>`, though?

Comment: offtopic: I like `grim` acronym it is so gloomy :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the answers from [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch) to write an alias which looks up the correct branch name, then use that inside other aliases:

```
# ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
    main-branch-name = "!f() { git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | sed \"s@^refs/remotes/origin/@@\" ; }; f"
    rm = ! git rebase $(git main-branch-name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this issue this way:

```sh
git rev-parse main >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && git rebase main || git rebase master
```

If there is `main` branch use it otherwise try with `master`.

It should be less lagging then use of `git remote show origin`.