# how can i change git_main_branch

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I used gcm(alias to git checkout $(git_main_branch)) to switch branches in my project, but switched to `trunk` branch, I expected to switch to master branch.

```
echo $(git_main_branch)
trunk
```

change git_main_branch to master rather than trunk. In my other project, git_main_branch is master as my expected

Comment: `git_main_branch` is not a Git command. You must have invented it yourself, or copied it from someone else who invented it themselves. You'll need to find out where your command comes from and/or where its documentation is, in order to figure out how to control it. [Hint](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Oh-My-Zsh_Git.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

Comment: I have found the [solution](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/9412)  in oh-my-zsh github issue.thx

Comment: @torek `git_main_branch` is a zsh function installed when you download oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 5):

You can override the function in your `.zshrc` like so:

```bash
function git_main_branch() {
  def=`git remote show origin | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p'`
  echo $def
}
```

refs:

- [dsayling comment on zsh issue](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/9412#issuecomment-1281296612)
- [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44750379/1677912)

Comment: I simply used `echo "master"` in this function

Comment: @LiranH that works only if all of your branches "main" branch is called "master". The provided answer here will work more dynamically for branches not named "master". Also I should point out that oh-my-zsh defaults should work for branches named master anyways, so should not require this override to begin with

Answer (score 1):

According to the [oh-my-zsh documentation](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/README.md#current), the `git_main_branch` function returns `main` branch **if it locally exists** or fallbacks to `master`.

If there's a desire `gcm`, `gswm` aliases switch to `main` branch, just make sure it exists locally.

Command to verify whether `main` branch exists locally:

```
git show-branch main
```

Answer (score 0):

The `git_main_branch` function is a part of the Git plugin in the `oh-my-zsh` Shell framework. The function's script can be located in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` file, or its equivalent according to your installation configuration.

You can inspect this function locally by running `which git_main_branch`. On my system, running zsh version `5.9`, the function looks like this:

```
git_main_branch () {
    command git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null || return
    local ref
    for ref in refs/{heads,remotes/{origin,upstream}}/{main,trunk}
    do
        if command git show-ref -q --verify $ref
        then
            echo ${ref:t}
            return
        fi
    done
    echo master
}
```

As per this implementation, the function initially searches for specific branch references defined in this array:

```
refs/heads/main
refs/heads/trunk
refs/remotes/origin/main
refs/remotes/origin/trunk
refs/remotes/upstream/main
refs/remotes/upstream/trunk
```

If none of these are found it returns `master`.
Based on your output you probably have `trunk` branch.

To circumvent this issue, you can either modify the script to check for `master` as the first element within the for loop, or alternatively, you can redefine the `git_main_branch` function to automatically return `master` as shown below:

```
git_main_branch () {   
    echo master
}
```

Don't forget to source your changes (or open a new terminal window) in order for this to take effect.