# Get the default branch name of git projects

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I used `repo init` to initialize and sync a source code. In the directory of a specific project I used

```
git branch -r
```

to list all the branches. The default branch of the project is called "stable", not main or master. How can I get the name of the default branch using git branch command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git - how to get default branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666357/git-how-to-get-default-branch)

Answer (score 2):

For a source code downloaded by `repo init` and `repo sync`, all projects and their branches are described in the manifest file specified by `-m`. The manifest has a `default` node and it has some attributes which could include `revision="foo"`. For a `project` node, if it has `revision="some_ref_name"` or `revision="some_sha1sum" upstream="some_ref_name"`, its default branch is `some_ref_name`. If it does not have these attributes, the revision in the default node is used. Note that the ref could be a tag or any valid git ref other than a branch. The default node and the project nodes could be like

```
<default revision="some_ref_name" remote="origin" />
<project name="repo1" path="repo1" revision="some_ref_name" />
<project name="repo2" path="repo2" />
<project name="repo3" path="repo3" revision="afbdb1ba3bb7de1aa9c86e501d4ef635bdf05354" upstream="some_ref_name" />
```

However, by default, `repo sync` checks out a detached HEAD from the ref head. A detached HEAD is more like an anonymous branch. Although it points at the same commit with the head of the ref at first, making a new commit based on the detached HEAD does not update the ref. Git commands like `git branch` or `git for-each-ref` do not help much.

If you want to get the default revision or upstream ref, the most reliable method is to parse the manifest file. In most cases, the manifest is a single xml file. It's easy to parse it or grep a regex in it. But the manifest file can have one or more nested manifest files. The `repo` tool also supports local manifests. And in practice there are more cases which involve multiple manifest files. After you successfully run `repo sync`, you could use `repo manifest -r -o foo.xml` to create a single manifest file first. And then grep the project name or path and find its upstream.

Say you want to find the default ref of the project named `bar` in `foo.xml`.

```
grep -E 'name="bar"' foo.xml | grep -oP '(?<=upstream=")[^"]+(?=")'
```